# Changing Theme produced a problem on some pages

Tags: images, themes, header-image

When I changed the Theme to Twenty Seventeen a few of the pages had the following text instead of the Header image:

> Notice: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/exclude-pages/exclude_pages.php on line 92
> class="page-template-default page page-id-835 page-parent logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support wp-embed-responsive ecwd-theme-twentyseventeen has-header-image page-two-column colors-light">

I have not been able to resolve his.

Comment: this looks like an issue with the `exclude-pages` plugin, have you contacted their support and made sure the plugin is up to date?

Comment: it looks like this was written by Simon Wheatley but it's abandoned and hasn't been touched in 12 years: https://wordpress.org/plugins/exclude-pages/ you should deactivate it and find an alternative

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering in WordPress suggests a notice-level issue in the code, specifically in the **exclude_pages.php** file of the 'Exclude Pages' plugin. This issue seems to be related to PHP's handling of variables and references. Here's how you can address it:

**Understand the Error:** The notice is indicating that a variable is being assigned by reference in an improper manner. This often happens when using the =& operator in PHP, which is used to assign a reference to a variable.

**Check Your PHP Version:** Different PHP versions may handle references differently. Make sure your server is using a PHP version that is compatible with both WordPress and your plugins. A more recent PHP version could be stricter about reference assignments.

**Edit the Plugin File:**

**Backup:** First, make a backup of the exclude_pages.php file.
Edit: Open /var/www/wp-content/plugins/exclude-pages/exclude_pages.php.
Find Line 92: Look for the code at line 92.
Update the Code: The exact change depends on the code. If it’s something like $variable =& some_function();, you can usually safely change it to $variable = some_function();. This removes the reference assignment.

**Alternative Solutions:**

**Update the Plugin:** Ensure the 'Exclude Pages' plugin is updated to its latest version. Plugin updates often fix such compatibility issues.
Check for Plugin Conflicts: Deactivate other plugins temporarily to see if the issue persists. Sometimes, conflicts between plugins can cause unexpected errors.
Switch to a Different Plugin: If the 'Exclude Pages' plugin is outdated or not maintained, consider using an alternative plugin that offers similar functionality.

**Testing and Debugging:**

After making changes, test your website thoroughly to ensure that everything is functioning correctly.
You can enable WordPress debugging by adding define('WP_DEBUG', true); in your wp-config.php file to see if any other issues arise. Remember to turn this off on a live site after debugging.
Contact Plugin Support: If you're uncomfortable editing plugin files or if the issue persists, it’s advisable to contact the plugin’s support for a resolution.

Remember, directly editing plugin files is generally not recommended because your changes will be overwritten when the plugin is updated. In such cases, contacting the plugin developer for a fix is the best course of action.